# How convert empty space between parts of a word multisectoral?

Tags: regex, linux, sed

how Convert empty space between parts of a word multisectoral by regex from this file line by line? and replace by "_" ? in linux (sed or ex)

from

```
0656.txt W * PUNC PUNC my word
0656.txt W * CONJ CONJ my best word
```

to

```
0656.txt W * PUNC PUNC my_word
0656.txt W * CONJ CONJ my_best_word
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is not a code writing service but help provider. Please show us what you have tried so far to solve this.

Comment: _"parts of a word"_ can be a lot of things. Can you elaborate a bit more the rules you wish in your regex? Anyways, maybe this help: `$ sed -r 's/(([a-z]+) ([a-z]))/\1_\2/g)' file`

Comment: What does `multisectoral` mean anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Your question if vague, and it doesn't have a strict goal (parts of a word)?.

```
keyword='my'

while read line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    replace=$(echo "$line" | sed -re "s/^.*($keyword)/\1/g" | sed -re "s/ /_/g")
    echo "$line" | sed -re "s/($keyword.*)/$replace/g"
done <"file.txt" >"outfile.txt"
```

This replaces the space between words after your keyword with underscores. It then inserts it back into the larger string.